# Passing folder as flag in regex

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to call a bash script passing flags, like this:

```
bash pdfgrep.ssh "STRING TO SEARCH" "FOLDER_TO_SCAN/*"
```

Script:

```
pdfgrep -H "$1" "$2"
```

This is causing:

```
poppler/error: Couldn't open file 'FOLDER_TO_SCRAN/*'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What does this have to do with SSH? That's a protocol and command for executing commands on a remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you quote the variable `$2`, that prevents the shell from expanding wildcards. So you need to do:

```
pdfgrep -H "$1" $2
```

However, this will have a problem if the folder name contains spaces, because it also does word splitting. It would be better if you allowed the original shell to expand the wildcard, by not quoting the argument to the script:

```
bash pdfgrep.ssh "STRING TO SEARCH" FOLDER_TO_SCAN/*
```

Then you need to change the script so it passes all the arguments to `pdfgrep`, not just the first two:

```
pdfgrep -H "$@"
```

Now I'm not sure what the point of the script is. All it does is insert the `-H` option to the beginning, which is less typing that `bash pdfgrep.ssh`.